# What are server logs and how to generate them?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, kibana, papertrail-app

Can someone please explain server logs and how to generate them for my Node.js website. I'm just getting started with this. What does kibana and paper trail do? How will these monitor my server?

Answer (score 0):

Logs are just output, used to monitor something or debug something.  They're usually in plaintext, with timestamps, and hopefully useful information, indicating what happened and when.

Server logs are generated from your server... your Node.js application.  When you output stuff indicating what happened (such as via `console.log()`), you're creating a log.

Kibana is a web-based tool for visualizing data in Elasticsearch, which is a document database.  Elasticsearch/Logstash/Kibana is a common setup for processing (Logstash), storing/indexing (Elasticsearch), and viewing (Kibana) your logged data.  If you go this route, I recommend using structured logs (such as a JSON output).

Papertrail is a cloud service for storing your unstructured log data.  It's commonly used with application hosting services like Heroku, as these services don't readily provide a place for you to write logs to a file on the filesystem.